# develop a menu item for a single item in joomla 2.5

Tags: components

how can I develop menu item for a single item at a joomla 2.5 component?
I develop menu item for category in my component but don't know how can 
develop menu item for a single item from my category.
please help me
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a single article from a category you would just use "single article" when creating a menu link. Then a new field will appear and you must select which article you want.

If you are referring to a component you need to make sure the component even allows the creation to the link you want. You do this the same way but instead of "single article" you would select the component then choose what links they offer as a menu link.

This refers to Joomla! 3.0+ for 2.5 or below you would see a full list without the show/hide effects in the menu selection modal.

If you use Joomla you know what I mean..

Hope this helps.